# pandas group by n seconds and apply arbitrary rolling function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some csv data of accelerometer readings in the following format (not exactly this, the real data has a higher sampling rate):

```
2013-09-28 17:36:50.322120,  0.152695, -0.545074, -0.852997
2013-09-28 17:36:50.622988,  0.141800, -0.554947, -0.867935
2013-09-28 17:36:51.923802,  0.132431, -0.547089, -0.879333
2013-09-28 17:36:52.124641,  0.124329, -0.530243, -0.887741
2013-09-28 17:36:52.425341,  0.122269, -0.519669, -0.900269
2013-09-28 17:36:52.926202,  0.122879, -0.502151, -0.902023
....
....
....
....
2013-09-28 17:49:14.440343,  0.005447, -0.623016, -0.773529
2013-09-28 17:49:14.557806,  0.009048, -0.623093, -0.790909
2013-09-28 17:49:14.758442,  0.007217, -0.617386, -0.815796
```

I loaded them using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
accDF=pd.read_csv(accFileName,header=0, sep=',') 
accDF.columns=['time','x','y','z']
accDF=accDF.set_index(['time'])
```

The accelerometer data is not uniformly sampled, and I want to group data by every 10 or 20 or 30 seconds and apply a custom function to the data group.

If the data was uniformly sampled, it would have been easy to apply a rolling function.
However, since it is not, I want to apply groupby using timestamp interval.
Doing so with an interval of one second is easy:

```
accDF_win=accDF.groupby(accDF.index.second).apply... etc
```

However, I cannot figure out how to group by an arbitary number of seconds and then apply a function to it.

With TimeGrouper, I can do the following:

```
accDF_win=accDF.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='3Min'))
```

for an arbitrary number of minutes, but seems like TimeGrouper doesn't have 'second' resolution.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have to convert the datetime-column to a python-datetime object (in case you did'nt).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> df=pd.read_csv("test.csv",header=None,date_parser=True)
#convert to datetime index, f.e. with dateutil
>>> df=df.set_index(df[0].map(parser.parse)
```

Then use the `pd.TimeGrouper` like this:

```
>>> df[3].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10S')).head()
2013-09-28 17:36:40  2013-09-28 17:36:40.322120   -0.852997
                     2013-09-28 17:36:41.622988   -0.867935
                     2013-09-28 17:36:42.923802   -0.879333
                     2013-09-28 17:36:43.124641   -0.887741
                     2013-09-28 17:36:45.425341   -0.900269
2013-09-28 17:36:50  2013-09-28 17:36:52.926202   -0.902023
                     2013-09-28 17:36:53.322120   -0.852997
                     2013-09-28 17:36:53.622988   -0.867935
                     2013-09-28 17:36:54.923802   -0.879333
                     2013-09-28 17:36:54.124641   -0.887741
2013-09-28 17:49:50  2013-09-28 17:49:56.440343   -0.773529
                     2013-09-28 17:49:56.557806   -0.790909
                     2013-09-28 17:49:57.758442   -0.815796
```

Or have a look at the resampling-functions [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html). Maybe you could apply a custom resampling-function instead of using the groupby-method.

```
df[3].resample("10S",how=lambda x: Whateveryouwanttodo)
```

Without any function, it fills up with NaN:

```
>>> df[3].resample("10S")
0
2013-09-28 17:36:40   -0.877655
2013-09-28 17:36:50   -0.884617
2013-09-28 17:37:00         NaN
2013-09-28 17:37:10         NaN
2013-09-28 17:37:20         NaN
2013-09-28 17:37:30         NaN
2013-09-28 17:37:40         NaN
```

Comment: Note that `TimeGrouper` has been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.21.0.html) in pandas 0.21 in favor of [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), with argument `freq`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a TimeGrouper. Resampling by the second is supported. You're [not the first person](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1914) to try 'S' for seconds (so maybe pandas should support it?); the correct string is 's'.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=True, sep=',', index_col=0, header=None)
df.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']
df.resample('10s', how=f)  # where f is your function
```

**Edit**: Actually here, on my version (the soon-to-be-released 0.13) I find that '10S' works as well. Maybe your whole problem was not parsing the dates.

Comment: Actually, he didn't even try "Sec" ;)

Comment: It looks like this changed at some point; maybe he has an old version of pandas where S and Sec are no good.