# efficient way to find unique values within time windows in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe that countains data similar to the image attached.

[image]

I want to get a count of how many unique TN exist within each 2 second window of the data. I've done this with a simple loop, but it is incredibly slow. Is there a better technique I can use to get this?

My original code is:

```
uniqueTN = []
tmstart = 5400; tmstop = 86400
for tm in range(int(tmstart), int(tmstop), 2):
    df = rundf[(rundf['time']>=(tm-2))&rundf['time']<tm)]
    uniqueTN.append(df['TN'].unique())
```

This solution would be fine it the set of data was not so large.

Comment: You can use the pandas groupby() method and then use the nunique() method on the 'TN' column.

Comment: Would that be able to give me 2 second windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas group by n seconds and apply arbitrary rolling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095593/pandas-group-by-n-seconds-and-apply-arbitrary-rolling-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can implement `groupby()` method and `nunique()`.

```
rundf['time'] = (rundf['time'] // 2) * 2
grouped = rundf.groupby('time')['TN'].nunique()
```

Another alternative is to use the `resample()` method of pandas and then the `nunique()` method.

```
grouped = rundf.resample('2S', on='time')['TN'].nunique()
```